# Create Javascript Variable with name of a variable and string combined

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I cant seem to solve this problem, heres what I have...

```
vid1=0;
vid2=0;
vid3=0;

num=1;

'vid'+num = 1;
// vid1=1;
```

I want to create the variable based on the number, so if the number is 2, then make a variable by the name of vid2 and set it equal to 1.

PS: This is my first time on stackoverflow, so sorry if I made any mistakes in terms of tradition on this website =) And thannks in advanced.

Comment: why not use array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - variable value is name of another variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14405252/javascript-variable-value-is-name-of-another-variable)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Variable Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592862/javascript-variable-variables)

Comment: @JonathandeM. sorry, i want to stick to my code

Comment: @epascarello nope, mines simpler

Comment: @FelixKling nope. mines simpler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're in the global namespace, use this:

```
window['vid' + num] = 1;
```

but this is a really good use case for an array:

```
var numbers = [0, 0, 0];
var num = 1;

numbers[num] = 1;
```

Comment: For more details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862193/javascript-global-variables

Comment: And where is the `eval` option?

Comment: @RobG - I don't go down the sewer drain without full body anti-toxic protective clothing. You get me that, and I'll get you `eval`.

Comment: I just think that for the sake of completeness, it should be mentioned (and warned against of course).